# Error when using password parameter in Py2neo when creating a Graph object

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to create a Graph object in python using the py2neo library using interactive python. See output below.

```
>>> from py2neo import Graph
>>> myGraph = Graph(password='xxxx')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password'

I don't understand why I'm getting the unexpected keyword argument error.

Comment: What version of py2neo are you on?

Comment: sorry, using V3 of Py2neo